# in status field should be approved once boolean field is true how to write syntax

Tags: python, django

[mode.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLpgw.jpg)

this image of model file in this once Boolean is true the status field value should be approved how to write syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can override save function as

```
class Cloudstrats1(models.Model)
    Projectname = models CharField(max_length=30)
    ProjectDetail = models.TextField()
    .........
    .........

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.Approved == True:
            self.status = 'approved'
        super(Cloudstrats1, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: it is not working status is same